# yarn install keeps looping when pushed to Heroku

Tags: json, reactjs, heroku

I have created a simple application with react and express and I am trying to use Heroku for hosting. When pushing to Heroku master, when it runs the "yarn" it shows the following:

```
 $ cd ./frontend && yarn
remote:        yarn install v1.22.10
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        success Already up-to-date.
remote:        $ cd ./frontend && yarn
remote:        yarn install v1.22.10
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        success Already up-to-date.
.
.
.
```

this is what I put in my package.json

```
{
  "name": "aras",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mafia video game",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PROD=true node server.js",
    "postinstall": "cd ./frontend && yarn"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.0.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

the package.json within my "frontend" folder has the following script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "yarn build"
  },
```

I checked some other similar issues but none was only repeating this one. the others suggested to reinstall the yarn, delete yarn, delete node modules. I have done all that but no changes.

Answer (score 1):

The `postinstall` script runs `yarn build`.

When pushing to Heroku, it automatically runs your `build` script if it exists. In this case you have a `build` script running `react-scripts build`. When that's finished, the `postinstall` script is run, in this case `yarn build`. That repeats the process, running `react-scripts` again and retriggering the `postinstall` script once it's done.

If this is sounding like a rerun of Who's on First, let me show a break down:

1. `build` -> `react-scripts build`
2. `postinstall` -> `yarn build`
3. `build` -> `react-scripts build`
4. `postinstall` -> `yarn build`
5. to infinity....

I'm not familiar with the intricacies of your app, but it could be that removing the `postinstall` script is a good place to start for a solution.